# Let $G$ be a finite group, $N$ be a normal subgroup. Suppose $|G|/|N| = 100$. Prove that for every $g$ in $G$, $g^{100}$ is in $N$.

Tags: normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $N$ be a normal subgroup. Suppose $|G|/|N| = 100$. Prove that for every $g$ in $G$, $g^{100}$ is in $N$.

How can i prove this question?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Given $g \in G$, the element $g + N \in G/N$ satisfies

$$(g + N)^{100} = e_{G/N} = N$$

Alternatively,

$$g^{100} + N = N$$

Comment: This is based on Lagrange's Theorem and one of its corollaries isn't it?

Comment: @Tristen Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Consider the factor group $\frac{G}{N}$. How many elements does it have?

What can you say in $\frac{G}{N}$ about $(g+N)^{100}$?